# Способ отображения страницы Spring MVC

Tags: java, mvc

Добрый день. Занялся изучением Spring MVC и задался соответствующим вопросом: какая технология в нынешнее время наиболее востребована и наиболее популярна для отображения пользовательского интерфейса? Знаю, что есть JSP, но не уверен, что сейчас она до сих пор актуальна. Также знаком с REST API и рендером на стороне клиента (React-Redux). Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Смотреть надо во все стороны. Изучить JSP, изучить пару-тройку шаблонизаторов, изучить разработку REST-сервисов и т.п. и т.п.

Comment: То есть, JSP до сих пор используются в продакшене?

Comment: Я вам сейчас скажу страшное: У java-технологий чудовищно длительные жизненные циклы. В _кровавом энтерпрайзе™_, который и является основным потребителем Java, большинству программистов приходится бо́льшую часть времени работать с кодом, написанным более 10 лет назад.

Comment: Учить все - бесполезно, в Java этих либ и технологий огромное количество. На подробное изучение каждой уйдет огромное количество времени, а поверхностно... А оно вам надо? Мой совет, выучите Themeleaf или JSP, или еще что нибудь, что лично вам приглянется, Когда вы поймете один шаблонизатор, другой пойдёт в 10 раз быстрее, этого будет достаточно чтобы на рабочем месте в случае чего разобраться в похожей технологии. Просто разброс технологии от компании к компании большой и лучше ваше время уделить чему то более важному, чем изучения шаблонизаторов.